# What does multiplication of an absolute value by a negative factor really mean?

Tags: arithmetic, absolute-value

I was wondering, if `-2*|-5|` is actually `-10`, why are we also taught that vertical bars used to denote absolute value behave just like parentheses: they are grouping symbols and values can be distributed over them, like `-2*((-2)+(-3)) = 10` because `(-2)*(-2)+(-2)*(-3) = 4+6`. So, is `-2*|(-2)+(-3)| = 10` or `-10`? Because we know that `-2*|(-2)+(-3)| = |(-2)*(-2)+(-2)(-3)| = |4+6| = 10`, and yet we also know that `-2*|(-2)+(-3)| = -2*|-5| = -2*5 = -10`. Which one is it?

I am confused, and would appreciate your help.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $-2*|(-2)+(-3)| = |(-2)*(-2)+(-2)(-3)|$

This equality is not true. Absolute values are not ***just*** a set of parentheses, but they also represent another operation of, in some sense, removing the sign from a number. This means that properties that hold for one thing may not hold for another.

In this case, the rule you'd want to use is
$$
|xy| = |x| \cdot |y|
$$
but this doesn't give you much to work with for your example since it lets you, at best, claim
$$
-2 \cdot |(-2) + (-3)| = -1 \cdot \Big| 2 \big( (-2) + (-3) \big) \Big|
$$
The negative can't go inside the absolute values. Otherwise you end up with nonsense like
$$
-1 \cdot |x| = |-x| = |x| = |1 \cdot x| = 1 \cdot |x|
$$
which, if $x \ne 0$, shows $-1 = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Absolute values **do not** behave like parentheses.

You can think of them as a process whereby you input a number on an absolute value and one of the two happens:

-If your number is positive the output is that exact number.
-If you input a negative number, the output is that number but with a preceding negative sign, so that the output is again positive.

If you are familiar with functions, the absolute value is a function, say $A(x), x\in \mathbb{R}$:

$$A(x)=\begin{cases} x \text{, if x}\ge0\\-x \text{, if x}\lt0 \end{cases}$$

It is clear that its range is $[0,+\infty)$.

You wouldn't say for an arbitrary function that $mA(x)=A(mx)$ so why make the claim for the absolute value?

As PrincessEev points out, the rule is $|x||y|=|xy|$.
We can say though that $x|y|=|xy|$ if $x\ge0$.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I have a side question: How does your function know which of the two cases to process when `x=0`? Shouldn't you define it as `x, if x≥0` and `-x, if x<0` (not `≤0`)? Or it doesn't matter?

Comment: @bp2017 You are correct. I should have chosen only one of the branches. I will edit accordingly. Once chosen (usually the positive branch), there is no issue. Thank you for noticing.